# Laravel-list data not show but no error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, builder

i want to show my list data from database. here is my controller :

```html
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Mmenu;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\ContactRequest;
use App\Http\Requests;

class MmenuController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $mmenu = Mmenu::orderby('id','ASC');
  return view('mmenu.index', compact('mmenu'));
    }
}
```

this my view code index.blade.php:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <a href="{{ route('mmenu.create') }}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Menu Baru</a>
    
    @if ($message = Session::get('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success martop-sm">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif

    <table class="table table-responsive martop-sm">
        <thead>
            <th>Menu Id</th>
            <th>Menu Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            @foreach ($mmenu as $a)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $a->id }}</td>
                    <td><a href="{{ route('mmenu.show', $a->id) }}">{{ $a->menu_name }}</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="{{ route('mmenu.destroy', $a->id) }}" method="post">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                            <a href="{{ route('mmenu.edit', $a->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Ubah</a>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Hapus</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@endsection
```

this my routes:

```html
Route::resource('mmenu', 'MmenuController');
```

when i load the page, list data not showing but no errors show :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXBhx.jpg)

Comment: Route::resource('mmenu', 'MmenuController@index'); And
Mmenu::orderby('id')->get();

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
$mmenu = Mmenu::orderby('id','ASC');
```

to:

```
$mmenu = Mmenu::orderby('id','ASC')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use get to get data.
So your function should be like this.
You can also use list,pluck etc.

```
public function index()
    {
        $mmenu = Mmenu::get()->orderBy('id','ASC');
        return view('mmenu.index', compact('mmenu'));
    }
```